# Is this result set possible with a left or right join?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I've got a questions table with unique questions and an answers table with the rows that correspond to answers submitted by specific users. What I'd like to do is create one query that returns a row for every question and includes the answer of the user who is logged in. If the user has not answered a question yet, the answer column should display NULL for that question. The query must return a row for every question regardless of whether the user has answered it or not, and should not return rows for answers by any other user.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`question` text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers` (
`fb_user` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`answer` text NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `fb_user` (`fb_user`,`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Currently I'm using two queries to make this work:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE answers_f SELECT * from answers WHERE fb_user = '$fb_profile_id'
SELECT questions.*, answers_f.* FROM answers_f RIGHT JOIN questions ON questions.id = answers_f.question_id ORDER BY questions.id
```

Question? Is there a way to use just one left or right join query with perhaps a subquery or mutiple join rather than have to create a temporary table as well as I've done above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write it as a single query you need to test the username as part of the join condition, not as a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
    questions.id,
    questions.question,
    answers.answer
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN answers
ON question_id = questions.id
AND fb_user = 'foobar'
ORDER BY questions.id
```

Comment: Perfect. You pegged the problem exactly. I used a WHERE instead of the AND in your solution. Thanks!